# Ribbon load balance algorithms

Tags: spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Spring Cloud with NetflixOSS in my microservice project. Also, I am using Ribbon with Feign Client as my client side load balancer. I was wondering, is there any possibility to implement or choose different types of load balancing algorithms for Ribbon? Because as I understood, the default is round robin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See [the docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR3/#_customizing_the_ribbon_client) for full details how to customize. For a `@FeignClient("foo")` and a random load-balancing rule you could do:

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "foo", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
public class TestConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        IRule rule = new RandomRule();
        rule.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
        return rule;
    }
}
```

See the [ribbon wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers#common-rules) for some more details and [here](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/tree/master/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer) for more implementations.