# how to variable (Ratio) load balance using Ribbon spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-ribbon

As I distributed similar instance to two different servers, my first server has good configuration but the second server have not enough memory for cache. So I want 80% of the requests being transfered to my first server and the remaining to the second server. How can I configure this using ribbon with spring boot?

Currently, it is working on round robin algorithm. the first request goes on first server and second go on the second one. 
I want to configure into 4:1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ribbon offers some prebuilt rules as documented here:
https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers

I think `WeightedResponseTimeRule` can be suitable in your case. Instead of statically defining a ratio, let Ribbon decide depending on the response times of the servers.

Or, you can define your custom rule as described here:
[Ribbon load balance algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992876/ribbon-load-balance-algorithms)